# How can I make an external PSU for an Apple IIc?

Tags: apple-ii, power

I purchased an Apple IIc from an auction site, but it came without the
external power supply unit. While [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12677/7208) and its
answers describe how to open up the IIc and use alligator clips to
power it from a bench PSU, I'd like something more convenient and
portable. What are my options for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The external power input on an Apple IIc is a male 7-pin DIN jack. The
standard Apple external PSU takes a country-specific input voltage
(105 to 129 VAC, 60 Hz for North America) and provides (unregulated)
15 VDC.

Though on [page 11](https://archive.org/details/Apple_IIc_Technical_Reference_Manual/page/n38) of the [*Apple IIc Technical Reference
Manual*](https://archive.org/details/Apple_IIc_Technical_Reference_Manual) it says that the internal power supply "operates
from a 12 to 15 VDC input source," this is actually too conservative.
[Page 234](https://archive.org/details/Apple_IIc_Technical_Reference_Manual/page/n261) of that manual gives the correct specifications:
the system unit accepts an input voltage of "+9 to 20 VDC" with a
maximum power consumption of 25 W. I have been using my IIc with 20 V
input with no problems.

Conveniently, a lot of modern laptop PSUs provide voltages in this
range, and also work on any wall voltage from 100 V to 240 V, 50 or
60 Hz. I have several Lenovo ThinkPad PSUs used with older X200-series
laptops (and many other models) with a rated output of 20 V 65 W, so
I decided to use one of those..

[Page 234](https://archive.org/details/Apple_IIc_Technical_Reference_Manual/page/n261) also gives the pinouts of the external power
connector. Three pins are PSU ground; internally these are all
connected together anyway so it's probably safe to connect just one of
the ground pins if you need to go that way. Two more pins are for
positive voltage and, again, these are also connected together
internally. The last two pins are unconnected.

Here's the pinout using standard DIN pin numbering. Beware: the
*Technical Reference* uses a different, non-standard pin numbering,
also included that as well below. A "jack" is the connector on the
computer, a "plug" is the connector on the cable, and "LI" means
"looking into."

```
DIN Numbering       DIN Numbering    Apple Numbering
LI female plug      LI male jack      LI male jack
      ∪                  ∪                  ∪
   7     6            6     7            7     1
 3         1        1         3        6         2
   5     4            4     5            5     3
      2                  2                  4

DIN    Apple   Function
1,4     6,5    +15 V DC
  2       4    Chassis ground (AC input ground)
3,5     2,3    Signal ground
6,7     7,1    Not connected
```

You'll obviously need an adapter to convert the laptop PSU output to a
female 7-PIN female DIN plug. Fortunately Lenovo changed their PSU
connector at some point causing people to sell converter cables into
which you can plug the round connector from an old PSU to convert it
to the new square connector. From AliExpress I bought I [this
adapter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000116172409.html) (under $1), and also a 7-pin DIN plug with a
*female* insert [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32860020971.html) (under 50 cents). (Actually, I
purchased several of each in case I messed something up.)

Building the adapter was relatively simple, but needs some care to
ensure you're connecting the right pins, and that pins are not
shorted.

1. The DIN plug I used had a cover that came up to very nearly the
   edge of the metal shield. This type of plug won't fit into the IIc
   because there's not enough clearance, so it needs to be cut back by
   about a centimeter. I did this with a [side cutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_pliers), ensuring that
   I left intact the square hole in the cover for the latching tab on
   the shield so that I could still remove the plug by grasping the
   cover and pulling.
2. I confirmed my understanding of the IIc's power connector by doing
   a continuity test on the power input pins. The three ground pins
   are shorted to each other and also to the shields of all the
   connectors on the back of the case (including the power connector
   itself). The two positive voltage input pins should be connected to
   each other and nothing else. It's important at this stage to ensure
   you have confirmed you're using the right pins, and you should re-check
   this on the IIc and the DIN plug after each step, ensuring both that
   the ground and positive voltage lines are connected and that they're
   not shorted to each other.
3. I cut off the square end of the Lenovo adapter and stripped back
   the cable jacket, exposing red (+20V) and black (ground) wires,
   which I stripped and tinned. After doing this you should plug the
   adapter into your PSU and confirm the voltage and polarity with a
   multimeter; it's quite possible that some adapter cables have
   different colour assignments.
4. I stripped some solid-core hook-up wire and used a small length of
   it to join the three ground pins together on the DIN plug. I used
   another length to join the two power pins. My plug's connector tabs
   had holes in them; I made sure for at least one hole for each line
   to leave enough space to thread through them the tinned wires from
   the adapter. I then confirmed from  the plug side that the two
   power pins were connected to each other, that the three ground pins
   were connected to each other, and that the positive voltage pins
   were not shorted to the ground pins.
5. I placed the DIN plug cover over the Lenovo adapter cable (this is
   easy to forget!) and then soldered the adapter cable's wires to the
   appropriate pins on the DIN connector. I then confirmed ground
   connectivity (the outside of the Lenovo barrel connector) to the
   ground pins and positive voltage wire connectivity (the inner
   surface, *not* the inner pin, of the Lenovo adapter) to the
   positive voltage pins on the DIN connector.
6. I checked the wire connections to the tabs on the DIN plug and
   trimmed them down a bit to ensure that they wouldn't touch the
   shield. (This isn't a big deal for the ground wire, since ground is
   shorted to the shield in the IIc anyway, but it's vital that the
   positive voltage wire not be at risk of contacting the shield.)
   Then I assembled the shield over the plug, pushed the DIN cover
   part-way on, and confirmed that the ground and power pins were not
   shorted together.
7. I pulled up the latching tab on the DIN plug metal shield to ensure
   that it would properly seat in the hole in the cover, pushed it all
   the way on, and then plugged the adapter into the PSU and confirmed
   that the voltage between the power and ground pins was correct.

Here's a picture of the assembled adapter and the parts used to make
it (click on the image to see a much larger version):

[image: Lenovo PSU to Apple IIc External Power Adapter]

In the foreground at the left is an assembled DIN plug; to its right
is a DIN plug cover and the plug itself between the two parts of the
metal shield. Above these, from left to right, are the back panel of
an Apple IIc (the external power jack is next to the power switch),
the assembled adapter, the plug from a Lenovo PSU, and the PSU itself.
Behind the assembled adapter is the original Lenovo-old-style to
Lenovo-new-style adapter that I cut apart to make my adapter.

Comment: Just an FYI that it appears the text of the pinouts may have an error in it. I've triple checked and I think Apple +15 V DC should be **5,6** and Apple Signal ground should be **2,3**. Thanks for the great write up! [edited by moderator]

Comment: @poifamus Good catch! Yes, in the table the DIN pin numbers were and are correct, but the Apple pin numbers were wrong and did not match the source before I fixed this with an edit. I've re-checked this against my working adapter to make sure that the above is correct.